# Testes unitários abstratos

Tags: c#, testes, testes-de-unidade, classes-abstratas

Estou com um problema ao usar classes abstratas para manter o código comum dos meus testes, inicialização encerramento etc... 
Utilizo uma classe concreta apenas para  inicializar as variáveis.
O código herdado da classe abstrata não é executado ao rodar os teste, acredito ser alguma configuração faltando, segue um código exemplo:

```
        namespace meusTestes
        {
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using NUnit.Framework;

            public abstract class AbTest
            {
                public abstract string getString();

                [Test]
                public void SharedTest()
                {
                    Assert.NotNull(getString()); //Don't execute
                }
            }

            [TestFixture]
            public class RealTest : AbTest
            {
                public override string getString()
                {
                    return " "; //Don't execute
                }

                [Test]
                public void InternalTest()
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(true); // Execute
                }
            }
        }
```

O teste InternalTest é executado corretamente, mas o testes herdado(SharedTest) da classe abstrata não, minha duvida é o porque o herdado não executa dodo que a documentação preve herança de testes.

Comment: `"O código da classe abstrata não é executado (...)"` Pelo que você postou, ela nem tem código que possa ser executado.

Comment: Na documentação do NUnit diz ser possivel herdar os testes, segue: May not be abstract - although the attribute may be applied to an abstract class intended to serve as a base class for test fixtures. http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5.9

Comment: Não tenho certeza do que pode ser, mas já experimentou escrever um override vazio? Algo do tipo: `public override void SharedTest() : base() { }`

Comment: Bem por ai, vou postar a resposta, valeu Cigano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a sugestão do Cigano segue o código:

```
namespace meusTestes
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    public abstract class AbTest
    {
        public abstract string getString();

        public virtual void SharedTest()
        {
            Assert.NotNull(getString()); 
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class RealTest : AbTest
    {
        public override string getString()
        {
            return " "; 
        }

        [Test]
        public void InternalTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true); 
        }

        [Test]
        public override void SharedTest() { base.SharedTest(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A classe `AbTest` **não** precisa ser abstrata, pois você não precisa se preocupar em  instanciar essas classes, uma vez que o NUnit fará isso para você.

Eu sempre uso classes de teste "base" para encapsular implementações que serão reutilizadas nas filhas e funciona tranquilamente para as chamadas de `base.Metodo()` e propriedades `protected`.

#### Solução

Remova os `abstract`.

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma solução, mas é que na pergunta eu não inclui, eu quero obrigar as classes filhas a implementar o método getString(). Algo muito parecido com Template method.